# How to merger the same value data in multidimensional array

Tags: php, php-7

My Code

```
<?php
$a = [
        ["memberID" => "1" ],
        ["memberID" => "2" ],
        ["memberID" => "3" ]
];

$b = [
        "1" => [ "hasUser" => false ],
        "2" => [ "hasUser" => true],
        "3" => ["hasUser" => true]
];


foreach ($a as $key => $userDeatils) {
    $a[$key]["userFound"] = $b[$userDeatils["memberID"]] ?? [];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);exit;
?>
```

In this code based on `$a` memberID i want to take the value`(hasUser)` from `$b` and push into `$a',i tried it is working but it creating separate array.

Getting Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [memberID] => 1
            [userFound] => Array
                (
                    [hasUser] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [memberID] => 2
            [userFound] => Array
                (
                    [hasUser] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [memberID] => 3
            [userFound] => Array
                (
                    [hasUser] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Expected output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [memberID] => 1
            [hasUser] => 

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [memberID] => 2
            [hasUser] => 1

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [memberID] => 3
            [hasUser] => 1

        )

)
```

Kindly anyone update my code based on my expected answer.I tried using foreach loop but i couldn't make my expected answer,kindly any one help me out on this

Comment: `$a[$key]["hasUser"] = $b[$userDeatils["memberID"]]['hasUser'] ?? false;`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [**array_walk()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
array_walk($a, function (&$val) use (&$res, $b) { $val['hasUser'] = $b[$val['memberID']]['hasUser']; });
print_r($a);
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/iigDX).

**Modification of you code:**

In your code you are adding wrong key `userFound` and assigning the indexed array from `$b`. You can modify you code accordingly to get your output.

```
foreach ($a as $key => $userDeatils) {
    $a[$key]["hasUser"] = $b[$userDeatils["memberID"]]['hasUser'];
}
```

Comment: Actually `??` is a "Null coalescing operator". It was added in PHP7. [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) is the official documentation of new features. It is a combination of `?:` and `isset()`.

Comment: Yes! I think the OP was trying to use ternary there. That's way I mention the ternary. But thank  you :)